# Specifying own (sub)section as the section in moderncv

Tags: sectioning, moderncv, cv

I am using moderncv to write my cv, cover letter and aditionally I want to write another page, containing a list (with the same layout style as the cv). I want to get rid of the "additional space" of subsection on the 2nd page. Maybe somehow to redefine an own section with the same fontsize and Color as the subsection of moderncv. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}                                                      


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}
\subsection*{FooFoo}

\clearpage

\section{Methoden}
\subsection*{Überwachtes Lernen}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression    & & Basiskenntnisse
\end{tabularx}

\section{Softwares}
.....
\end{document}
```

That is, what I want:

[image]

Note, that I only want to reduce the space of the subsections on the 2nd page and not in the cv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add `\color{color1}` and `\large` with the appropriate spacing
in a command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\usepackage{tabularx}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.3cm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\name{Name}{name}
\title{Lebenslauf}                             
\address{...}{...}
\phone[mobile]{...}                   
\email{Mail}                                                      


\def\msubsection#1{%
\noindent{\color{color1}\large #1\vspace{8pt}\par}
}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Foo}

\section{Foo2}

\subsection{FooFoo}

\clearpage

\section{Methoden}
\msubsection{Uberwachtes Lernen}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression    & & Basiskenntnisse
\end{tabularx}


\section{Methoden}
\subsection*{Uberwachtes Lernen}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{10cm}Xp{5cm}@{}}
Lineare Regression & &Sehr gute Kenntnisse \tabularnewline
Logistische Regression    & & Basiskenntnisse
\end{tabularx}

\section{Softwares}
.....
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome @Vala. Happy TeXing!